# How to join models in django serializers?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to join two models, but I got the wrong result. How to do it right?

My models:

```py
class MoocherPage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)


class MoocherResource(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(blank=False, null=False)
    moocher = models.ForeignKey(MoocherPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

And serializers:

```
class MoocherResourceSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        URL_FIELD_NAME = 'url'
        model = MoocherResource
        fields = ('url', )


class MoocherPageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    resources = MoocherResourceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MoocherPage
        fields = ('name', 'bio', 'resources')
        depth = 1
```

I expected

```
{
    "name": "KissofLove",
    "bio": "I'm the kiss of love and I collect money for all lovers of the world.",
    "resources": ["https://stackoverflow.com/users/KissofLove"]
}
```

But the `resources` was not included.

---

When I change `read_only=True` to `False` in the nested serializer an error appears.
`AttributeError: Original exception text was: 'MoocherPage' object has no attribute 'resources'.`

Comment: inherit `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` instead of  `ModelSerializer` for your `MoocherResourceSerializer` if you do not have a `url` field in the `MoocherResource` model

Comment: @minglyu I tried to change both and one of the serializers, added `URL_FIELD_NAME='url'` to `Meta`. It didn't work.

Comment: `fields` expects iterable, change your fields -> `fields = ('url', )`, add a comma to make it a tuple, otherwise python treat `(url)`  as a  `'url'` (str)

Comment: @minglyu good remark, but it didn't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your models

```
class MoocherPage(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=48, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    bio = models.TextField(blank=False, null=False)


class MoocherResource(models.Model):
    url = models.URLField(blank=False, null=False)
    moocher = models.ForeignKey(MoocherPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

and your serializers,

```
from rest_framework.serializers import *

class ResourceListingField(RelatedField):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        return value.url


class MoocherPageSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    resources = ResourceListingField(many=True, source='moocherresource_set', read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = MoocherPage
        fields = ['name', 'bio', 'resources']
```

This returns the desired

```
{
"name": "KissOfLove",
"bio": "I'm the kiss of love and I collect money for all lovers of the world.",
"resources": ["https://stackoverflow.com/users/KissofLove"]
}
```

response.

Check out [Custom relational fields](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#custom-relational-fields)